# Using requestFocus() to jump from field to field automatically. But it's jumping to the wrong field - sometimes

Tags: android

This is a weird one.  I'm setting up a simple pin-code login for my app.  There are four numerical EditText password fields in a series.  Their IDs are pin1, pin2, pin3 and pin4 and each has a MaxLength of 1.

The idea is, when you type a number in the first EditText field, it automatically jumps to the next EditText field.  After you type the 4th number, it verifies it and either launches the main activity, or lets you know your PIN was wrong.

The code for this is very simple and straight forward.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pin_login);

    final EditText pin1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin1);
    final EditText pin2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin2);
    final EditText pin3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin3);
    final EditText pin4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin4);


    pin1.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
            if (keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                pin1.clearFocus();
                pin2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                pin2.requestFocus();                    
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    pin2.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
            if (keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                pin2.clearFocus();
                pin3.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                pin3.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    pin3.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
            if (keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                pin3.clearFocus();
                pin3.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                pin4.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    pin4.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
            if (keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                pin4.clearFocus();
                pin1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                pin1.requestFocus(); // this is just temporary testing code
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pin1"
        android:labelFor="@id/pin1"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:width="56dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pin2"
        android:labelFor="@id/pin2"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:width="56dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pin3"
        android:labelFor="@id/pin3"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:width="56dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pin4"
        android:labelFor="@id/pin4"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:width="56dp" />
```

The problem is that I'm getting really strange behavior.  The pin login activity starts up in the `pin1` field ready to type.  As soon as I press a number, 80% of the time it jumps to `pin3` field, instead of `pin2`.  And sometimes `pin2` jumps to `pin4` instead of `pin3`.  And so on.  It's very random.

Very odd behavior.

Another problem is that the passwords fields sometimes do not get masked.  Usually they turn into dots as expected, but sometimes they remain visible numbers indefinitely.

Here's a screenshot that sort of shows the issues: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jAxk.png
and this is the series of events that occured:

- I typed a number into PIN1
- It skipped PIN2 and went to PIN3
- I typed 5 in PIN3
- It skipped PIN4, and went back to PIN1
- PIN3 remained unmasked

Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: You can remove `pin?.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` and return true inside`if` condition, if it is `true`.

Comment: @Pr38y if I return true, it doesn't put anything at all in the edittext fields.

Comment: @user1003916 I am having same problem. Did you find any solution?